# Width of table cell with absolute content

Tags: html, css

i need my table to be as wide as it's needed even when its content is absolute and wider than whole page. So when i zoom and top schema div is becoming wider, table will expand its cell. Thanks.

```css
.topToolbar,.botToolbar{
 background-color: red;
 height:100%;
}

.leftToolbar,.rightToolbar{
 background-color: blue;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;;
}
.mdi{
 position:relative;
 overflow:auto;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color: grey;
}
.schema{
 border:10px solid green;
 position:absolute;
 top:300px;
 left:300px;
 width:600px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:white;
}
.schemaBot, .schemaTop{
 border:10px solid green;
 top:0px;
    position:absolute;
 left:600px;
 width:600px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:white;
}
.schemaLeft, .schemaRight{
 border:10px solid green;
 position:absolute;
 top:300px;
 left:0;
 width:30px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:white;
}
.tbl tr:first-child td,.tbl  tr:last-child td{
 position:relative;
 height:50px;
}
.tbl tr:nth-child(2)  td:first-child,.tbl  tr:nth-child(2)  td:last-child{
 position:relative;
 width:50px;
 height:100%;
}

.tbl tr:nth-child(2)  td:nth-child(2){
  
 
 }
.tbl{
 border-spacing:0px;
 min-width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
td{
 padding:0px;
}

html, body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <body>
 <table class="tbl">
  <tr>
   <td colspan=3>
    <div class="topToolbar">
     <div class="schemaTop"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <div class="leftToolbar">
     
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div class="mdi">
     <div class="schema"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div class="rightToolbar">
     
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan=3>
    <div class="botToolbar">
     <div class="schemaBot"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
 </body>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean `table to be as wide as it's needed`?

Comment: as you can see in js fiddle, table is not wide enough to cover those 2 divs on right, you can scroll to see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's not possible for div to keep absolute content within, absoulte content will always overflow and doesn't affect parent div size

Answer (score 0):

Set your schemaTop class to width 100%.

```
   .schemaBot, .schemaTop{
      border: 10px solid green;
      top: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: white;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Try this one

```
 .schemaBot, .schemaTop{
          border: 10px solid green;
         top: 0px;
         position: absolute;
         left: 36%;
         width: 36%;
         height: 30px;
         background-color: white;
   }
```

Comment: thats the point, schemas width and position is user defined so it can't be in % and position needs to be absolute. I only need that table to change its width when user zoom page so it still show schema in table and just show scrollbars

Comment: "schemas width and position is user defined so it can't be in %"